# Disable scrolling of CustomScrollView while scrolling without setState Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview, physics, reload

I have multiple widget and lists within `CustomScrollView` and I would like to stop `CustomScrollView` to scroll while scrolling on some pixels bound condition.

I can use `NeverScrollPhysics()` to stop it but I don't want to use `setState()` function here because the CustomScrollview content with lists is big enough to make the screen laggy while reloading on scroll.

Also tried with `Provider` but the builder is providing only a child widget which is not working with sliver list.

Here is the code using `setState()` :

```
              NotificationListener(
                  onNotification: (ScrollNotification notif) {
                    if(notif is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                      if (canScroll && notif.metrics.pixels > 100) {
                        canScroll = false;
                        setState(() {});
                      }
                    }
                    if(notif is ScrollEndNotification) {
                      if(!canScroll) {
                        canScroll = true;
                        setState(() {});
                      }
                    }
                    return true;
                  },
                  child: CustomScrollView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: canScroll ? BouncingScrollPhysics() : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), 
                      slivers: [
                        SliverToBoxAdapter(),                                              
                        List(),
                        List(),
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
```

Is there a way to reload only the `CustomScrollView` without its child ? Otherwise any workaround to prevent scrolling in this case ?

Thanks for help

Comment: use Stream instead of setState.

Comment: Did you mean ```StreamBuilder``` ? It's the same as ```Provider``` in this case, would reload the entire content of the ```CustomScrollView```.

Comment: You need a state management solution, such as bloc or riverpod.

Comment: @7mada I'm already using Provider but it doesn't solve this

Comment: I know Provider won't solve this problem, but RiverPod and Bloc can, if you want to use RiverPod I can write you an answer that will solve the problem.

Comment: If i understand correctly, with Riverpod i am able to not reload items in CustomScrollView when it's rebuilt ? And only reload constructor param ?  If yes, then please write an answer and I'll test . If it's working I'll migrate my project to RiverPod.  Thanks for help

Comment: Why do you use `shrinkWrap: true`? Without that line it should not be laggy with `setState(...)`.

Comment: @Mäddin  I'm using this because shrinkWrap is killing the top BouncingPhysics but no at bottom . I need this. And I tried with and without there no difference

Comment: Sorry for being late @nicover, I didn't get a reply notification :(.
Any way I will write the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the build method is called, all widgets in that build method will be rebuild except for `const` widgets, but `const` widget cannot accept dynamic arguments (only a constant values).

`Riverpod` provides a very good solution in this case,
With `ProviderScope` you can pass arguments by `inherited widget` instead of widget constructor (as when passing arguments using navigation) so the contractor can be `const`.

Example :

Data module

TLDR you need to use `Freezed` package or override the `== operator` and the `hashCode` almost always because of dart issue.

```
class DataClass {
  final int age;
  final String name;

  const DataClass(this.age, this.name);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is DataClass && other.age == age && other.name == name;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => age.hashCode ^ name.hashCode;
}
```

setting our `ScopedProvider` as a global variable

```
final dataClassScope = ScopedProvider<DataClass>(null);
```

The widget we use in our list

```
class MyChildWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyChildWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final data = watch(dataClassScope);

    // Note for better optimaization
    // in case you are sure the data you are passing to this widget wouldn't change
    // you can just use StatelessWidget and set the data as:
    // final data = context.read(dataClassScope);
    // use ConsumerWidget (or Consumer down in this child widget tree) if the data has to change

    print('widget with name\n${data.name} rebuild');

    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40, horizontal: 20),
        child: Text(
          'Name : ${data.name}\nAge ${data.age}',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

finally the main `CustomScrollView` widget

```
class MyMainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyMainWidget();

  @override
  State<MyMainWidget> createState() => _MyMainWidgetState();
}

class _MyMainWidgetState extends State<MyMainWidget> {
  bool canScroll = true;

  void changeCanScrollState() {
    setState(() => canScroll = !canScroll);
    print('canScroll $canScroll');
  }

  final dataList = List.generate(
    20,
    (index) => DataClass(10 * index, '$index'),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () {
          changeCanScrollState();
        },
        child: CustomScrollView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: canScroll
              ? BouncingScrollPhysics()
              : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          slivers: [
            for (int i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++)
              ProviderScope(
                overrides: [
                  dataClassScope.overrideWithValue(dataList[i]),
                ],
                child: const MyChildWidget(),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget to wrap the `MaterialApp` with `ProviderScope`.

```
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this . Didn't know about Riverpod

Answer (score 2):

###### Try this solution use const constructor for child widget so it won't rebuild unless widget changed

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  ValueNotifier<ScrollPhysics> canScroll =
      ValueNotifier(const BouncingScrollPhysics());

  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NotificationListener(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification notif) {
          if (notif is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
            if (canScroll.value.runtimeType == BouncingScrollPhysics &&
                notif.metrics.pixels > 100) {
              canScroll.value = const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
              debugPrint("End false");
            }
          }
          if (notif is ScrollEndNotification) {
            if (canScroll.value.runtimeType == NeverScrollableScrollPhysics) {
              debugPrint("End");
              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  () => canScroll.value = const BouncingScrollPhysics());

              debugPrint("End1");
            }
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: canScroll,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, ScrollPhysics scrollType, Widget? child) =>
                  CustomScrollView(
            physics: scrollType,
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't create const Constructor unfortunately . My lists contain users item with multiple param variable . Thanks for help

Comment: @nicover above solution work mostly with less rebuild time can you give a try? And try to split slivers content with stateless & stateful widget

Comment: I tried your code. Unfortunately I can't do to this in my use case . slivers item are rebuilt and my lists make the screen laggy on scroll. Anyway your answer is useful for another case

Answer (score 0):

Are you just need to stop the user from scrolling it? I think you can try to controller the list to a fixed position by using **jumoTo**.

```
  ...
  final _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notif) {
        if (notif is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
          if (notif.metrics.pixels > 100) {
            _controller.jumpTo(100)
          }
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _controller,
        ...
```